# How to prove that $|x| = inf_{(y_1,y_2) \in \mathbb{R^2}} \ y_1 + y_2$

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, real-numbers

I need to prove that for every real number $x \in \mathbb{R}$ holds:

$$|x| = inf_{(y_1,y_2) \in \mathbb{R^2}} \ y_1 + y_2 \ $$ such that $$x = y_1 - y_2 , \ y_1 \ge 0 , \ y_2 \ge 0$$

I think the direction $\le$ is pretty obvious, but I don't know how to do the other one, i.e. $\ge$. Could you give me a hint on how to do that?

Comment: The first step would be writing the problem in a correct and clear form. You cannot solve a problem like you posted it. The condition after "such that ..." belongs also inside the condition of the infimum, right?

Comment: If $x\geq0$, then $y_1=|x|, y_2=0$ is a feasible point since $x=|x|=y_1-y_2$. Then $y_1+y_2=|x|$. If $x<0$, then $y_1=0,y_2=|x|$ is a feasible point. In that case $y_1+y_2=|x|$ too. Therefore $|x|\geq \inf_{...}(y_1+y_2)$.